# What is the need of static member functions when we can modify the static data members by using normal functions?

Tags: c++, static, static-members

What is the need of static member functions when we can modify the static data members by using normal functions. I got confused on the need of static member functions. Please help me to get clarification on this...

Comment: Is someone going around today just upvoting every single post that gets submitted?

Comment: I did not understand, why that question came here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the need of static member functions

You need to declare a member funtion of a class as a static to be able to call it without instantiating an object.. look for Singleton pattern for example.

> when we can modify the static data members by using normal functions?

not all the time ! you can't modify static data member from non-static member function unless you instantiate an object first. On the other hand, you can always do that from static member function, whether you instantiated an object or not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two reasons: one technical and another is about code readability. Technical side is simple: static method is still a method of the class so it has access to it's private members. It is part of the class and it is OK that it knows all internals of the class.

But more important thing is that classes are name spaces. They structure your code. By using static method you tell everybody that it belongs to the class and is tightly related to it.

Comment: Normal member functions can also access the private members of the class. Is there anything that only static functions can do and members cannot do?

Comment: Seems that I've misunderstood your question. Under "normal functions" I understood usual free functions, which are not part of any class. And "member functions" are usually called methods.

Comment: Oh yeah!!! I missed to add normal "member" functions.

Answer (score 1):

`static` means (in context of a class) that you can always call the method like `ClassName::MethodName()` instead of `ClassName instance; instance.MethodName`.

Means - you can call static member functions from non-static member functions, but not the other way round given that the static member function doesn't own one or more instances of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Static functions can be called without creating any object of the class .

e.g. 

Let's say you have a class Street which contains number of houses and a static method addHouse() which increments number of houses by 1.

You want to create a new house so you can just call addHouse() in the constructor of House. If you created non static member , then you would have to create a new object of Street every time you created an object for  House.

```
class Street
{
    static int numberOfHouses = 0;
public:
    static void addHouse()
    {
        numberOfHouses ++;
    }
    void incrementHouse()
    {
        numberOfHouses++;
    }


};
class House
{
public:
    House()
    {
        Street::addHouse();
        //this will not create a new object for Street
        Street s;
        s.incrementHouse();
        // you would have to allocate memory for extra object of street class for this.
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Static within a class means the data do not pertain to the object created, but to the class itself. The data will be the same(not equal, but the same, same address) for all objects.

A static method will make the compiler ensure that it only messes with static data. It alsos makes it more clear, as when you see a static method, you know it doesnt need any 'alive' object data.